# What is the proper way to "store" data with PowerShell

Tags: powershell-2.0

I have to handle quite a lot of results and store them. I'd like to create something like a tab which I could in the end export as a CSV.

I was using a `PSObject` with quite a lot of members. I wonder if there is a better way to handle this? If you can show me how to create it and input data it would be nice.

I should create a tab witch look like this:

```
Site 1    | Tester | result Test 1 | Result test 2 |.... |Result test x
Sitename1 | tester1| Fail          | Succes        | fail| etc...
Sitename1 | tester1| Succes        | Fail          | fail| etc...
```

PS: It has to be working with PowerShell v2.0.

Comment: Are you looking for [`Export-Csv`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv)?

Comment: I will use export-csv to export data. I'm looking for a way to handle the tab within powershell

Comment: Keep using custom objects. That's what you need for `Export-Csv` anyway.